# How do I debug a JS map mutating values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nvm

I have an example below where in React I'm just mapping through some state and showing it again, but for some reason it's changing the value of `hidden` inside. This is only specific to my machine as my colleague's machine doesn't show this error. I've tried nuking my node modules and restarting and different node versions. Wondering if there's anything else I can do. Thank you.

```
  fetchExample() {
    console.log('state', this.state.columns) => [{ foo: { hidden: false }] }
    const result = this.state.columns.map((col) => {
      return { ...col };
    });
    console.log('result', result); => [{ foo: { hidden: true } }]
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: What's the type of `this.state.columns`? It should be an array to map over but your code comment mentions it as an object. And what you're trying to achieve with the `map` transformation? There's no way for the value of `hidden` to change unless you're doing some other transformation. Is there any other code in the `fetchExample` function not being shared?

Comment: It was an array and I forgot to put it in

Comment: You're cloning the outer object, but the object at `foo` is passed as a reference, so any changes to `foo.hidden` will affect all references.

Comment: This is just an example so how how my spread isn't working, I originally was adding in a key but just running it like the code example the value gets changed